# Fail when install konga in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, konga

When I try to install konga using docker. I received message : Unknown authenticationOk message typeMessage { name: 'authenticationOk', length: 23 }.

I have searched and tried several solutions but it still can't work.

I using Postgre v14.2.

Could you please check it?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.